# Get method passing all values on form mvc3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

```
 @using (Html.BeginRouteForm("ProductSearch", FormMethod.Get))
    {
        <div class="page-title">
            <h1>Search</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="clear">
        </div>
        <div class="search-inut">
   //here there is code for product box of each product satisfying search condition
}
```

All products are passed as querystring, any way to avoid it?
e.g

http:\localhost:54632\mysite\q=sugar&sugar 5kg=1&sugar free=1..............

all the products in search result are added in querystring

Thanx

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
    //here there is code for product box of each product satisfying search condition
}
```

to

```
}
//here there is code for product box of each product satisfying search condition
```

MVC isn't like Web Forms (where your entire page was in a form), you can safely put parts outside the form.